# How to develop an online code repository?

Tags: git, repository

I basically want to create a code-repository on my server, where a few of my friends and I can share code snippets. However, I cannot afford to spend on the already available ones.And the free ones wont allow me to keep my code to myself.
Please help me out here.

Comment: You have the answer as one of your tags. Just run your own git server.

Comment: The free ones (at least some of them) *will* allow you to keep your code to yourself.  One example: http://www.assembla.com/.

Comment: As Chris says. But as a side issue, why keep your code to yourself? Programming isn't a zero-sum game :) And only a small percentage of the coding that gets done is genuinely novel. There's little to gain unless you're planning to commercialise what you create.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz Why not run around naked all the time? (Some people do :-) There are many -- personal or other -- reasons not to want to share code (or other data) with the public in general.

Comment: @pst: Each to his own. I'm not sure the comparison is a fair one though -- sharing your coding assets is arguably of greater benefit to humanity as a whole than sharing your...ahem...other assets :)

Comment: *shrugs* I guess I just have more sympathy for people who are offering something in exchange for the free stuff they want.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "the free one's won't allow me to keep my code to myself"? If you are worried about permissions pretty much all of them (shy of CVS) implement user level security. There is some administration overhead involved but should provide the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: I think perhaps, "only public [aka Open Source] repositories" (e.g. like github), which is not really true either :) I think one or two such sites as counter-examples would round this question out, +1 otherwise.

Comment: The question was about using their own server. I didn't realize I could host GitHub on my own server? Now that would be a neat feature.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your use of the `git` tag, I'm assuming you are specifically interested in git. You might want to read [Chapter 4](http://progit.org/book/ch4-0.html) of [Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/), an online book by Scott Chacon. It covers the various protocols and options for running a git server.

That said, running your own server will probably be more expensive than buying private hosting somewhere like [github.com](http://github.com), unless you're already running a server anyway.

Comment: Know of any "github alternatives" that allow "private repositories" for free? (bitbucket, which is hg and not git, has limited support for "free private repositories" in this manner -- just asking as an off-hand question :)

Answer (score 0):

As well as being able to host your own git server there are at least 2 free providers out there that will allow you to host private projects.

My personaly favorite is BitBucket.org , assembla.com is another.